# CORS policy: Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header field in preflight response

Tags: java, angular, cors

I have a CORS issue with my angular & spring boot app. I don't understand what it is.

[CORS policy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhD6t.png)

My angular code :

```html
login(user : User)
  {
  return this.http.post<User>(this.apiURL+'/login', user , {observe:'response'});
  }
```

and to the server side, i allow cross origin like that

```html
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers," +
                "Origin, Accept, X - Requested - With, Content - Type, Access - Control - Request - Method," +
                "Access - Control - Request - Headers, Authorization");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization, Access-ControlAllow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials ");
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Spring application you should have a security configuration file, you can call it SecurityConfig.java.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                // other config here
    }

 CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

}

Try this and see if it works.

In your Spring Controller you should also have this annotation before your controller class @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
Check if 4200 is the port you use for your Angular app, if not change it with your port.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4201")
@RestController
public class YourController {
....
```